# Library Window at DevCPP

Tags: c, dev-c++

i'm trying to use window.h at devc++, i installed devc++ without mingw and installed MinGW32 separeted.

I'm trying to compile an souce code that have `#include <window.h>` but appear an error.

> window.h: No such file or directory.

What can i do to be able to compile with window.h at dev c++?

At compiler options i had added path to `mingw32\bin and mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32`.

What can i do to solve that?

Comment: What's `window.h`? Do you mean `windows.h`? If yes, you have a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use `#include <windows.h>` instead, which is the typical include statement for the Windows header file. Note the 's' in the `windows.h`.